# configuring DNS with media temple virtual dedicated server and domain management with godaddy

Tags: dns

I want to know how to configure my DNS zone file in GoDaddy for the following:

- ftp
- webmail

The Scenario:
The dedicated virtual server (dv) is with mediatemple and the domain management is with GoDaddy. I have the "A" record for myDomain.com setup correctly to point to the dv because when I reached my index page when I type www.myDomain.com on my browser. I was also able to setup a subdomain (mySub.myDomain.com) correctly.

Note:
It's interesting that when I do an nslookup for myDomain.com I get the IP of goDaddy. I thought that I would get the IP address of my dv server.

In any case, I'm new at this and I'd like to hear recommendations on how I should configure the ftp and webmail in goDaddy.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, where do you want you ftp and webmail to point? I'm assuming your talking about configuring `ftp.mydomain.com` and `webmail.mydomain.com`? And you may not necessarily get the IP of your 'dv' if you just lookup `mydomain.com` simply because you can get to it via `www.mydomain.com` if you have set up an A record for `www.` but not for the root of the domain. The standard way of handling something like this is to configure `www.` as a CNAME of the root and pointing the root record at the 'dv'.

Comment: Dave - thanks for your response. The A record for mydomain.com was pointing to godaddy's secureserver. When I fixed it to point to my dv server at mediatemple, the ftp worked as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to mt support, I configured the ftp and webmail successfully. Below is how I configured my dns zone file in godaddy.

Create the correct A records for the dv server including mail and webmail. There should be a CNAME record for the ftp which points to the ip of the dv server.

```
myDomain.com 'A' <ip of dv server>
mail.myDomain.com 'A' <ip of dv server>
webmail.myDomain.com 'A' <ip of dv server>
```

Point an MX record to your dv server

```
myDomain.com 'MX' preference:0  exchange:mail.myDomain.com
```

Delete the remaining MX records

I had to wait 24 to 48 hours for these changes to propagate.

Comment: this was exactly what i was trying to figure out for myself.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pointing your A record is not the same as pointing your nameservers. If you wish to use (mt) nameservers, you should point them at (mt): http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/5/%28mt%29+Media+Temple%27s+DNS%7B47%7DNameserver+information

I'm also confused as to what you're asking as far as "pointing" FTP and Webmail to your (dv). If you open a support request, give us a call, or message us on Twitter, we'd be happy to give you a hand.